# Overcome SkyDrive Pro 2 GB limit

Tags: 2013, onedrive-for-business

or a 3rd party tool like StoragePoint - does anyone have experience removing the file storage for SkyDrive Pro so that individual files can't exceed the 2GB limit?  StoragePoint looks possible, but it seems I'd have to train users to use the "Upload Large File" which is a little much to ask.

I can't find much discussion on it, but this is pretty much driving my users to Dropbox

Thanks for any advice,
Ross

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about skydrive

Comment: SkyDrive Pro seems to be based on older version of ASP.NET technologies, whereas the 2GB limit for supported uploads was only raised in ASP.NET 4.5. So you're not likely to easily work around it in the current version.

Comment: @ArkoD It's SkyDrive Pro, which is a SharePoint Library in the personal site, therefore this is not off topic.

Comment: Ross - Is this on premises or in 365?